# Transactions Stuck. Offline transaction cancelling is not working either

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

Transaction is stuck pending, so I used Myetherwallet to generate an offline transaction with the same nonce as the pending transaction, YET once the transaction is posted, I see that the nonce generated is higher than the chosen number.

The first pending transaction with nonce 12. (While the block explorer says its pending, metamask labels it as cancelled)
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x506bc1cded5cca7fac98a75dca45a0590cc6b7ade7f195ee16beed6b35bb490d

The second transaction used to cancel the previous one - https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6749f3c4a2603df1b910b30f5aee8c246975f347e62eabf119b9e8d02d0fffc1

Comment: EDIT - Metamask labels it as *Failed* , NOT Cancelled

The first pending transaction with nonce 12. (While the block explorer says its pending, metamask labels it as cancelled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transaction with nonce 12 was mined in block 9,835,994.

There might be some difference in the description of the result between Metamask an Etherscan. In the blockchain it was recorded as the transaction executed but it reverted with message "Pool: Insufficient unlocked funds". Any possible change was discarded only the transaction fee was paid.

The intended "replacement" has different nonce so it didn't replace. Perhaps there's an error in the code to generate an offline transaction or a copy&paste error.

Comment: Ah - yes, finally etherscan shows as such now. But Metamask still labels them as pending.

BUT got it to work by trying it from a diff machine - All transactions went through.

And yes, wtr to the replacement transaction, I code could have had errors but what is surprising is multiple offline transactions generation services all had the same error. Really confusing.

All that said, the past few hours have been a rollercoaster. Jesus